# NodeJs mirror website proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy, mirror

How would you write a server that simply mirrored a website when a request was received? For example, hitting `http://localhost:5000` which is running NodeJS would render cnn.com with images and everything. Is this called a passthrough proxy?

I'm not looking for something that requires configuring an actual proxy within your browser settings, but instead just serves up essentially a mirror of another site by passing the requests through.

Comment: Node.JS (or anything HTTP-based) really isn't the best way to do this. Would something like a SOCKS proxy work for you? Those are a lot simpler to set up and don't require anything beyond a server with SSH capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

First, let me make sure I understand your question.

You want to have your users browse to http://mynodeproxy.example.com and have that page in their browser render as if it was http://cnn.com. Right?

The answer is: You can't do it the way you think you can. This is possible with 2 approaches:

1. Users configure a real proxy server in their browser settings (this is why all browsers support configuring a proxy server). You could use an existing proxy server or try to write your own with node and some specialized application logic. But the point is the user's don't type your proxy address into the browser's address bar. They type your proxy address into their browser settings "proxy server" field and still type "http://cnn.com" into their browser address bar.
2. If you control all outgoing traffic from your network, you can do hotel-style tricks like DNS hijacking or routing all traffic through your proxy.

But this won't work by having your users put your passthrough proxy server address in their browser's address bar because the HTML your proxy gets from CNN.com is going to have hyperlinks back to other cnn.com resources (other pages on the site, images, fonts, CSS, JS, etc). If those links include the hostname instead of being relative to the containing HTML document, the browser will connect directly to cnn.com to load them, bypassing your proxy.

Now imagine the CNN HTML has a link like `<a href="http://cnn.com">View the CNN Home Page</a>`. What happens when the user clicks that? That's right, your proxy is entirely out of the picture and bypasses. This is why proxy servers work with explicit browser support.

Once CNN.com's javascript starts doing things like making ajax requests, dynamically adding stuff to the DOM, etc, you will see this is not possible by simply proxying and modifying the initial cnn.com home page HTML. Yes, you could do this for an extremely trivial contrived example web page, but realistically a modern popular site like cnn.com, it's not feasible.

Comment: I don't want to proxy all requests, just have http://localhost:8000 serve up cnn.com, and that's it. I'm not looking for a regular proxy that needs to be configured int he browser settings, but instead just a way to forward the request so that I'm serving up a mirror of some site.

Comment: So "just cnn.com" is likely to be dozens of requests, including content from many other hosts like content delivery networks, youtube, etc. It's a "web". It's just not that simple.

Comment: I completely understand that. Stuff off-domain is fine, but everything towards the same domain should be forwarded/mirrored.

Comment: I think you've nicely rephrased the question, but I think there is a way to do without an actually http proxy configured into the browser. See http://tomodo.com/. I understand that not everything will work (like links, which you point out), but just the initial rendering would be fine and pass-through XHR's.

Comment: So yeah, the http-proxy module is your friend, but let's just say it's complicated and no one can answer exactly based on not knowing what you consider required and what is OK to be broken, so if you're hoping for someone to paste you a code snippet, I don't think anyone will. You could also just render it via phantomjs to an image and send back the screenshot if that's all you need.